# Stacker AwsvpcConfiguration passed in as yaml and recieved as str

Tags: python, yaml, troposphere

I'm trying to get a [Stacker](https://github.com/remind101/stacker) project (uses [Troposphere](https://github.com/cloudtools/troposphere) under the covers) up and running and I've been able to create several resources but am failing to figure the subnet piece out.  I've tried to pass them into my blueprint class several different ways but I think this one is closest and it's similar to the other implementations that don't outright explode.  The idea is to accept some configuration for a subnet like this.

In my `my_cluster.yaml`, I have:

```
 stacks:
 ...
  - name: cluster-networks
    description: "Networks for an ECS cluster"
    class_path: blueprints.networks.Networks
    variables:
      Networks: 
        InternalComms:
          AssignPublicIp: False
          SecurityGroups: 
            - sg-id
          Subnets: 
            - subnet-id1
            - subnet-id2
```

and to read that config, i have a blueprint called `blueprints/networks.py` that has this in it:

```
class Networks(Blueprint):
"""Manages creation of networks for ECS clusters"""

# Variables that are passed from the my_cluster.yaml
VARIABLES = {
    "Networks": {
        "type": TroposphereType(ecs.AwsvpcConfiguration, many=True),
        "description": "Dictionary for ECS cluster networks"
    }
}

def create_template(self):
    """method that Stacker calls to manipulate the template(s)"""
    variables = self.get_variables()
    for config in variables['Networks']:
        network = ecs.NetworkConfiguration(config)
        t.add_resource(network)
        # do other useful stuff like set outputs
```

If you're wondering why I create an `AwsvpcConfiguration` object and then create a `NetworkConfiguration` object out of that, the reason is because I tried to pass this information in using a `NetworkConfiguration` object before I adopted the `AwsvpcConfiguration` object and it didn't work either.  I'm using this [file](https://github.com/cloudtools/troposphere/blob/master/troposphere/ecs.py) to guide me because it's where these objects are defined. The next step is to `build` the resources, so when I do that by running this command:

```
stacker build path/to/my.env path/to/my_cluster.yaml
```

I get an error that says this:

```
stacker.exceptions.ValidatorError: Validator 'AwsvpcConfiguration.create' 
failed for variable 'Networks' with value 
'{'InternalComms': {'AssignPublicIp': False, 'SecurityGroups': ['sg-id'], 'Subnets': ['subnet-id1', 'subnet-id2']}}': 
TypeError: _from_dict() argument after ** must be a mapping, not str
```

This is probably my lack of skills at stacker, yaml and python but I'm stumped and have been for a day or so.

I am not able to figure out how to pass the config from the yaml into the blueprint as a dictionary, like I am doing in an identical manner for other resources that do get successfully created in AWS-land.  If you could point me to the error(s), I would be much obliged and will for sure tell Santa all about how nice you were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

troposphere maintainer/stacker author here.  So a few things:

1. You want to use `TroposphereType(ecs.NetworkConfiguration, many=True)` since that's the type of object you want to create.
2. ecs.NetworkConfiguration (https://github.com/cloudtools/troposphere/blob/master/troposphere/ecs.py#L71) is a AWSProperty type, which means the values inside of it, if using "many" needs to be a list of dictionaries per: http://stacker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/blueprints.html#property-types

So what I think you want is in your config

`variables:
  Networks:
    - AwsvpcConfiguration:
        AssignPublicIp: False
        SecurityGroups: 
          - sg-id
        Subnets: 
          - subnet-id1
          - subnet-id2`

This is because `TroposphereType` expects you to pass in the exact arguments that the type expects.  A `NetworkConfiguration` expects a single key, `AwsvpcConfiguration`, and the values you were passing were values that were expected by the `AwsvcpConfiguration` object.

The bigger question now is how you expect to use those objects.  In Cloudformation/troposphere, Property types aren't created on their own - they used as properties of actual resources- in this case the `ecs.Service` type.  Are you not planning to include the Service in the same blueprint?  If not, what is your plan to share these properties with other blueprints where those services live?

A better fit might be to have a blueprint that builds the service along with it's `NetworkConfiguration`.  Then, if you want to have the same NetworkConfiguration easily shared between multiple stacks using that blueprint, you can do something with YAML anchors like:

`common_network_configuration: &common_network_configuration
  - AwsvpcConfiguration:
      AssignPublicIp: False
      SecurityGroups: 
        - sg-id
      Subnets:
        - subnet-id1
        - subnet-id2`

And then use it wherever you want in variables like:

`variables:
  << : *common_network_configuration`

I hope that makes sense - if you have any more questions, you can always reach us on the stacker Slack as well: https://empire-slack.herokuapp.com/

Have a good one!

Comment: "he bigger question now is how you expect to use those objects."  I'm still working out the details but the blueprint and yaml I showed above are excperts.  The real blueprint orchastrates a cluster.  So far I have a few stacks; 

1. `permissions` contains a role, policies etc.
2. `network` ...sort of obvious
3. `init' contains launch config
4. `run` contains autoscaling group, which references the `network` stack's output(s)
5. `cluster` just a `ecs.Cluster()` that outputs its name and some other stacks that might be less interesting.
Thanks!

Comment: That fixed that error and now I'm working through others.  Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction and the yaml anchors for network config are probably a lot better than creating a stack and referencing it, like I was trying.  Have a happy holidays, amigo!
by the way, i'm impressed with what you've got with Stacker, so far.  Thanks for the good work!

Comment: Thanks @Adam!  Glad it got you going again.  In general, when we (@Remind) figure out our stacks, we tend to think about a few things:

- how often will it be updated?  Keep often updated stuff (like security group rules) separate from not often updated stuff (the security groups themselves)
- How dangerous is it to accidentally update?  protected mode & locking help  protect you from this in stacker, but it's still a good idea. It's safer to accidentally update a security group rule than it is to say, modify a subnet.

Good luck, and definitely stop by the slack channel sometime :)